# Html agility pack parsing Website encoding iso-8859-1 REALLY ANNOYING

Tags: windows-phone-7, webclient, html-agility-pack

I have been parsing this website for my windows phone app using Html agility pack;

First I download it using webclient class and then give the result for HtmlDocument.

There was some problems with iso-8859-1 encoding but htmlentity.DeEntitize solved problems with letters Ö ä showing as &Ouml and &auml...

But the document still has some scandinavian characters (äö) in some random encoding (which are showed as: �).

Those letters show perfectly using chrome.

site is: http://reittiopas.tampere.fi/mobile/fi/

Comment: Just tried the URL you provided out, and I can't see any `�` characters

Comment: Alex, you don't see the characters because your browser fixed them (it can handle that encoding, but Windows Phone, can't!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone only support a small set of encodings, and iso-8859-1 is not one of them!

To solve this, just create the encoding handler with [Silverlight Encoding Generator](http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator), convert the text, and then use HTML Agility Pack as you are now!

Comment: Thanks Pedro, I'll check this out! Is it ok to use the string from DownloadStringAsync or do I need some stream from webclient? Can you explain why the ie browser in windows phone handles that site properly?

Comment: The Windows Phone browser does handle iso-8859-1 encoded sites, but there isn't support for it in the Windows Phone SDK, hence the problem - I think DownloadStringAsync converts the data to UTF-8 (one of the available encodings in the SDK) so you see it with those weird chars; i'd go with the stream, get the byte array from it, and finally convert using the encoding class you get by using the Silverlight Encoding Generator!