# Reading BIG5 encoded data using XmlReader on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, character-encoding, big5

I am trying to get a XML content from here link. Then get the content of "item" element to display on screen. It's kind of RSS Reader on WP7. The issue were when I examine the content, the bytes seems have been modified (translated) with different encoding way, which should be using BIG5 but it is not. However, the native browser does show those BIG5 encoded characters though. Don't know how they get it.

I tried this

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URL) //URL to a XML file on Internet
while (reader.Read())  // iterate through the document
    switch (reader.NodeType)  
        case XmlNodeType.Text:  
            string s = reader.Value; // The string displayed as garbage
```

And I tried to use the EncodingGenerator as suggested by Jesse, but that didn't work as it doesn't support multibyte encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the non-support of the BIG5 encoding is an issue of Windows Phone in general, not of XmlReader. So you'll end up with the same issue if you switch to the HtmlAgilityPack.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277767/736079 for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like I will have to give up now. The encoding generator does not provide double byte encoding. So, I am still wondering if there is a way to get raw data without their any conversion?

Comment: You might want to change the question to explain exactly what you're trying to do, decode BIG5 encoded content from a website using the Windows Phone 7 API's. As it isn't really an issue between XMLReader or HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: @essehouwing, I am trying to get a XML content from here [link](http://feeds.feedburner.com/nownews/politic). Then get the content of "item" element to display on screen. It's kind of RSS Reader on WP7. The issue were when I examine the content, the bytes seems have been modified (translated) with different encoding way, which should be using BIG5 but it is not. However, the native browser does show those BIG5 encoded characters though. Don't know how they get it.

Comment: The browser doesn't run in Managed code, so it doesn't have all the limitations your custom application would have.